# Does using passenger defeat the purpose of using RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rvm

From what I can tell, Passenger can only be configured to use one version of Ruby.  So being able to easily switch between versions of Ruby with RVM is kinda pointless since Passenger has to to be reconfigured each time you want to switch versions of Ruby.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True, Apache/Passenger only allows one Ruby interpreter to be used at a time. You could get around this by installing multiple copies of Apache, one for each of the Ruby versions that you will end up deploying to. You could then set up reverse proxies in your main Apache to all your other servers running on different ports.

You can also use "passenger start" in your app directories, but this has all the same limitations of "rails s" or "./script/server" etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so necessarily. I guess it depends on how often you need to switch your Ruby, since most of my projects use REE 1.8.7, I don't find myself needing to switch often. As for configuring Passenger, the offender that needs to be updated when swapping is in the httpd.conf of Apache - the lines you're instructed to put in on the initial install - as they reference a specific version path as you know.

In addition, I just find installing Ruby via RVM just more simple than installing it normally, even if it isn't swapped often.

Comment: So can I just switch out the settings in the httpd.conf when I wwitch rubies or do I need to rerun the passenger install script

Comment: I rerun the second line of the install to get the exact lines I need at the end, then add it inot my httpd.conf, yes. Another thing to consider is that Passenger will let you run multiple Rails sites together easy (without having to launch server scripts) and being able to juggle across sites (if you need to) is beneficial enough to make this extra step worth it, IMO. It isn't everyone's ideal workflow granted, but depends on what you're doing and how often you plan on switching Ruby versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you never want to switch version of ruby then sure that might be fine. But realistically, you'll be changing versions. Plus, the benefits of using rvm far outweigh the cost (It's very easy to use so not much of a cost there)